# Problem with npm install --global http-server

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-init, testserver

I'm trying to install a test server in vscode using `npm install --global http-server`, after I cd to my current folder where my code is, when I run the command I'm supposed to get a node_modules folder and then I should run `npm init` to get package.json, however that's not the case and instead I get this message after running install server:

```
changed 34 packages, and audited 35 packages in 12s

7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

And when I try to run npm init, it asks me for the name of the file I want to create and some other parameters such as author, license, etc. I tried looking in the forum but I couldn't solve it yet.

Comment: “*when I run the command I'm supposed to get a node_modules folder*” Not quite - can you share how you reached the conclusion that this should happen when you install a package to the global path with `--global`?

Comment: I'm taking a web development course provided by the government of my country(Argentina) and they gave us a PDF that was initially talking about typescript and nodejs and at some point in the pdf, it said that I had to run that command and I should see the node_modules folder in my proyect's directory. I assumed I had to cd there, I tried without installing globally and still got the same message. But my problem was solved anyway, now Ill look how to install it globally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `--global` parameter, which tells npm to install the module into the global path, not in the local `node_modules/`.

If you need to install `http-server` as part of a project, first run npm init and then

```
npm install --save-dev http-server
```

or

```
npm install --save http-server
```

Comment: Thank you! it really helped me, I first ran npm init and created a file named package, then I ran npm install --save http-server and I got the node_modules folder! Then I opened package.js and edited the scripts part like this: "start": "http-server -p 8456" and it worked.