# how to install http in terminal in Macbook pro 2021?

Tags: node.js, terminal, backend, iterm2, macos-monterey

I'm trying to install http using terminal for vscode in Macbookpro

this is the website that I use and what I try to install:

p5.js manager
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdWleSHQTcw
sudo npm install -g p5-manager

Workflow: Node
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjWbUK2HdCo
sudo npm install http-server -g

I can't even use sudo in terminal due to password but I just type the password and a weird box pop up what to do next?

//

When I use Mac terminal then I can't even click on the key and I can only press **enter** only

**using Mac terminal:**
➜  ~ sudo npm install -g p5-manager

Password:

Sorry, try again.

Password:

Sorry, try again.

Password:

sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

//

I keep getting error and password key keeping popping up, by using iterm2

using item2 terminal
click on key a box appear I type my password then a box appear, close the box , then same error 3 incorrect password again

First:
[image: first/Pic1]

Second:
[image: Pic2]

Third:
[image]

Fourth:
[image]

yes I don't know what to do next in the **Third Picture**, so I just click **close**, same error...

//

how to know if http install which command line do I use, like how I know if I install node.js by typing "node -v"

//

and how to uninstall http or any other that I just install in the terminal, I just want to uninstall "npm install --save http-server" that I just type in terminal a few day ago in this website

[Problem with npm install --global http-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70642913/problem-with-npm-install-global-http-server)

Comment: It's super-unclear what problem you're having other than not knowing your sudo password.

Comment: I just click the key then as you can see in the Second picture, I use the password then as you can see in the Third picture, don't know what that is so I click close, then as you can see in the Fourth picture when I press enter

Answer (score 0):

I just go to YouTube type "**mac sudo terminal password key**" found this **video**:

**Entering Password in Terminal - MacOS and Unix based system**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNKiU9aOFB4

I guess the reason I did not get it the first time cause I do not understand how the terminal work, basically when you type in the password in every website it show dot 1 to 10 like this password.........., but for terminal only key and nothing change, so just type password then press enter